# Variable Resolution with Tensorflow for Superresolution

Tags: python, tensorflow, resolution, inference, tensor

I am using tensorflow to scale images by a factor of 2. But since the tensor (batchsize, height, width, channels) determines the resolution it only accepts images of only one resolution for inference and training.

For other resolutions I have to modify the code and retrain the model. Is it possible to make my code resolution independent? In theory convolutions of images are resolution independent, I don't see a reason why this wouldn't be possible.

I have no idea how to do this in tensorflow though. Is there anything out there to help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure how to do it in tensorflow, but in keras (which uses tensorflow as a backend) you can specify an input of unknown size for a convolutional layer (as specified [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1920) for example). I suspect you can do something similar in tf, by not giving the size of the variable a priori, for example using `tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=None)`

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so here is what I did:

input and output tensors now have the shape (batchsize, None, None, channels)

The training images now have to be resized outside of the network.

Important reminder: training images have to be the same size since they are in batches! Images in one batch have to have the same size. When inferencing the batch size is 1 so the size does not matter.